# Excel to VB: Can't read the zero behind

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm doing a connection with excel and I have a problem when I try to use an ID that have 0 behind...

I'm using a `ListBox` and add the IDs from the excel's worksheet as items. IDs have 9 numbers, like "123456789" or "098765430". So that I remove the last 4 characters to search the IDs with the same 5 numbers and add in another `ListBox`. It works fine, except with the codes with 0 (zero) behind.

```
Dim ConnectionString As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Tabela_Precos.xlsx; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        ConnectionString.Open()

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da

For i = 0 To Form1.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        Dim str As String = Compras.ListBox1.Items(i).ToString
        Dim prod As String = str.Remove(str.Length - 4)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE ID like '%" & prod & "%'", ConnectionString)

        ListBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i).Item(0))
Next
```

Comment: Excel formatting is most likely eating trialling zeros. Do you only care about first five characters? And what problem you have. Exception?

Comment: Yes I care. Doing the query, the rows doesn't exist. IndexOutOfRangeException. (I have formated the listbox to show the zero)

Comment: So listbox is showing exactly what you want? yes? And do you have problem with leading zeros too?

Comment: You state "It works fine, except with the codes with 0 (zero) behind." that implies the pattern ends with zero.  Is this what you really mean?  Or do you mean that the pattern starts with zero?  If it is the ones that start with zero, the ID column is most likely being read as type Double and the starting zeros are not part or the conversion to string for the Like comparer.  Try this select: `"Select * From [sheet1$] Where (Format([ID], ""000000000"") Like '" & prod & "%')"`

Comment: Yes the ListBox show exactly with the zeros "012345678" but comparing with the Excel, is like "12345678"...
OMG thx @TnTinMn It worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Excel file has the *ID* column entered as integer values, but is formatted for left-zero padding to present as a nine character field.  Your Excel db connection is reading the values as numbers (type Double, even-though they are integers).  Your original select statement is implicitly convert *ID* to a string for the `Like` comparison; however, this conversion does not now you want left-zero padding.  To use this type of comparison, you need to format *ID* yourself.

`Select * From [sheet1$] Where (Format([ID], ""000000000"") Like '" & prod & "%')"`

As you have indicated in the comments above, this works.  However, it is not the most efficient in terms of speed.  Since *ID* is numeric, it should be faster to do a numeric comparison.  You have already defined a `String` variable named `prod` and the following solution uses that variable to prepare a numeric value for use in constructing an alternate select based on your criteria.

`Dim prodNum As Int32 = Int32.Parse(prod) * 10000I`

Then the `Select` statement would become:

`"Select * From [sheet1$] Where ((([ID]\10000) * 10000)=" & prodNum.ToString & ")"`

These examples use a concatenated select statement, and ideally you would not do it this way, but rather use a parameterized statement with replacement values.  I'll leave that exercise up to you to perform.